# To generate and keep log files ongoing for the last 5-7 days in XML in log4j.xml

Tags: java, xml

I have the below XMl code snippet to generate last 5-7 days of log data. Once it crosses the 5MB limit all debug.log files are deleted and new ones are created.

```
 `<log4j:configuration>

<appender name="DEBUG" class="org.apache.log4j.RollingFileAppender">
  <param name="File" value="logs/debug.log" />
    <param name="MaxFileSize" value="5MB" />
    <param name="MaxBackupIndex" value="11" />
  <param name="Threshold" value="DEBUG" />
  <layout class="org.apache.log4j.PatternLayout">
    <param name="ConversionPattern" value= "%d{yyyy-MM-dd HH:mm:ss} [%t] %-5p %c - %m%n" />
  </layout>
</appender>`
```

I want to keep the log files ongoing for the last 5-7 days.Suppose If i check the logs on 10th of June data should be available from 5th to 10th and if i check the logs on 11th of June, data should be available from 6th to 11th and likewise. How can i do it? Please let me know if you need more clarification.

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0):

http://logging.apache.org/log4j/2.x/manual/appenders.html#RollingFileAppender

Read the manual :)

Hint: Triggering Policies